# Where is the "Log in with Stack Exchange" option?

Tags: discussion, bug, login

How to login for AskUbuntu, there is a new login-screen.

But the `Log in with Stack Exchange` disappeared, that's the way I always did it. I don't have a seperate AskUbunut account.

I don't see it.

So i tried to reset my password, and I got a mail to

```
You can log in to Ask Ubuntu using the following credentials:
 Choose the "Log in with Stack Exchange" option
```

But where is it?

Comment: Isn't the email and password option in http://i.stack.imgur.com/tz11H.png for the Stack Exchange login?

Comment: Login is being rewritten right now so error messages/help text probably haven't caught up with the new design. Muru is correct, just log in with your SE email/pw combo.

Comment: Somehow, it only started working after resetting my password.

Comment: Is this still broken after one month?